# Find the minimum value in golang?

Tags: go

In the language there is a minimum function https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Min But what if I have more than 2 numbers? I must to write a manual comparison in a for loop, or is there another way? The numbers are in the slice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to find the min between two integers in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516387/what-is-the-correct-way-to-find-the-min-between-two-integers-in-go)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there isn't any better way than looping. Not only is it cleaner than any other approach, it's also the fastest.

```
values := []int{4, 20, 0, -11, -10}

min := values[0]
for _, v := range values {
        if (v < min) {
            min = v
        }
}

fmt.Println(min)
```

**EDIT**

Since there has been some discussion in the comments about error handling and how to handle empty slices, here is a basic function that determines the minimum value. Remember to import `errors`.

```
func Min(values []int) (min int, e error) {
    if len(values) == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("Cannot detect a minimum value in an empty slice")
    }

    min = values[0]
    for _, v := range values {
            if (v < min) {
                min = v
            }
    }

    return min, nil
}
```

Comment: Gives wrong result if the slice only contains positive values, e.g. `[]int{4, 5}`.

Comment: Since now you unconditionally index the first element, it causes a runtime panic if the slice is empty, e.g. `[]int{}`.

Comment: And again - what should be the result for an empty slice?

Comment: The zero value for the result type, optionally signalling that it is not valid (e.g. `ok bool`).

Comment: @icza yep, I know, but this code should just stand as an example, for clarity I left out checks like this. This answer wasn't intended to be a full comparison function

Comment: Then you can print that there is no min (not applicable).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from go 1.21 you have an inbuilt function `min` for finding the minimum value

https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Min_and_max

Answer (score 1):

General answer is: "Yes, you must use a loop, if you do not know exact number of items to compare".

In this [package](https://github.com/adam-lavrik/go-imath) `Min` functions are implemented like:

```golang
// For 2 values
func Min(value_0, value_1 int) int {
    if value_0 < value_1 {
        return value_0
    }
    return value_1
}

// For 1+ values
func Mins(value int, values ...int) int {
    for _, v := range values {
        if v < value {
            value = v
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Comment: The answer would be much more helpful if you could include the said examples in he answer in a short and readable way.

Answer (score -3):

You should write a loop. It does not make sense to create dozens of function in standard library to find min/max/count/count_if/all_of/any_of/none_of etc. like in C++ (most of them in 4 flavours according arguments).

Comment: The `math.Max()` could have been variadic.

Comment: I don't think so. It has to be more complicated, because what will be the result for none argument?

Comment: For `func Max(x float64,  xs ...float64) float64` that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Only call for ar := []int{1, 2, 3, 4} would be more awful.